# How do I go through the String to make sure it only contains numbers in certain places?

Tags: java, regex, string, if-statement

I am writing something that will take a user's input for a phone number and tell the user if their input was valid or not based on five parameters:

1. input is 13 characters in length
2. char at index 0 is '('
3. char at index 4 is ')'
4. char at index 8 is '-'
5. All other characters must be one of the digits: ’0’ through ’9’ inclusive.

So far I have everything down except the 5th parameter. My code for that goes as followed

```
   if (number.contains("[0-9]+"))
    {
        ints = true;

        if (number.contains("[a-zA-Z]*\\d+."))
        {
            ints = false;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        ints = false;
    }
```

(Side note: number is my string that is the user's input, and ints is a boolean declared earlier in the code).

Comment: match with regular expression rather than checking contains

Comment: You can write a regex and match it with

Comment: String.contains() doesn't take a regex as an input. This would never match what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following. If the string is correct it will print `valid`, otherwise it will print `invalid`.

```
public void compare(){        
    String inputString="(123)848-3452";
    if(inputString.matches("^\\([0-9]{3}\\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}")){
        System.out.println("valid");
    }else{
        System.out.println("invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: This was perfect, I just used the first if statement and then put "ints = true;" instead of the System.out.println that you had. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regular expression to do it.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\(\\d{3}+\\)\\d{3}+-\\d{4}");
    System.out.println(p.matcher("(916)628-4563").matches());
    System.out.println(p.matcher("( 916 ) 628-4563").matches());
```

output:

**true**
**false**

It can be tough to enter data like this and when receiving user input you should try to limit their options. eg. ask for each part of the phone number, and omit (,) and -.

As the op has added new requirements. First check for the required (,), and -'s.

```
boolean goodNumber = number.find("(")==0&&number.find(")")==4
goodNumber = goodNumber&&number.find("-")==8
goodNumber = goodNumber&&number.length()==13&&
goodNumber = goodNumber&&number.replaceAll("\\d","").length()==3;
```

Find the brackets, the dash and then remove all of the numbers and see if you are only left with a bracket and dash.

Comment: I wish I could, as that makes more sense but for the assignment the professor wants it all to be done with just one user input using booleans and if else statements

Comment: @Dakota how is the accepted answer different from the answer I first supplied you?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a simple regex like this

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}\\-\\d{4}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(071)234-2434");
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```